# plotting regression lines in grey scale

Tags: r, regression, plotly

I am trying to plot regression lines on transpiration against sampling day for four species, however I am using a code, that specifies colored lines. I want to use the following code, but instead use black, white and grey colors.

```
plotly_interaction <- function(data, x, y, category, colors = col2rgb(viridis(nlevels(as.factor(data[[category]])))), ...) {

 require(plotly)
 require(viridis)
 require(broom)

 groups <- unique(data[[category]])

 p <- plot_ly(...)

 for (i in 1:length(groups)) {
   groupData = data[which(data[[category]]==groups[[i]]), ]
   p <- add_lines(p, data = groupData,
                  y = fitted(lm(data = groupData, groupData[[y]] ~ groupData[[x]])),
                  x = groupData[[x]],
                  line = list(color = paste('rgb', '(', paste(colors[, i], collapse = ", "), ')')),
                  name = groups[[i]],
                  showlegend = FALSE)
   p <- add_ribbons(p, data = augment(lm(data = groupData, groupData[[y]] ~ groupData[[x]])),
                    y = groupData[[y]],
                    x = groupData[[x]],
                    ymin = ~.fitted - 1.96 * .se.fit,
                    ymax = ~.fitted + 1.96 * .se.fit,
                    line = list(color = paste('rgb','(', paste(colors[, i], collapse = ", "), ', 0.05)')), 
                    fillcolor = paste('rgba', '(', paste(colors[, i], collapse = ", "), ', 0.1)'),
                    showlegend = FALSE)
   p <- add_markers(p, data = groupData, 
                    x = groupData[[x]], 
                    y = groupData[[y]],
                    symbol = groupData[[category]],
                    marker = list(color=paste('rgb','(', paste(colors[, i], collapse = ", "))))
 }
 p <- layout(p, xaxis = list(title = x), yaxis = list(title = y))
 return(p)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
plotly_interaction(iris, "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Species", colors = col2rgb(c("black", "white", "grey")))
```

Gives this:

[image]

Comment: this is super helpful!!!! thanks so much,  however-   how would the code further be modified in that case? I am kind of confused about why it pastes 'rgb' in addition to pasting 'colors' which is already declared in the first line of the code, for example here                                                                                                         line = list(color = paste('rgb', '(', paste(colors[ [, i], collapse = ", "), ')'))

Comment: Hi @sonalisaha. Yep. Me too. (; First. plotly.js and R differ in the way colors are supported. See e.g. https://plotly-r.com/working-with-colors.html, e.g. plotly doesn't work with all R color names or the colors may differ. Second. One reason for all the pasting in the function body is to some transparency to the colors used for the ribbons.